# XQuery Nodes with identic attribute values

Tags: xml, xpath, distinct, xquery

I have an XML Document of the following Structure.

```
<Content>
<Function Name="A">
    <SubNode1>
        <SubNode2>
        </SubNode2>
    </SubNode1>
</Function> 
<Function Name="B">
    <SubNode1>
        <SubNode2>
        </SubNode2>
    </SubNode1>
</Function> 
<Function Name="A">
    <SubNode1>
        <SubNode2>
        </SubNode2>
    </SubNode1>
</Function>
```

Now I want to display all functions with XQuery, using this code.

```
for $currentFunction in $node where local-name($currentFunction) = 'Function'                       
return
(
    <Function>
    {
       local:printAttributes($currentFunction)
    }
    </Function>
)
```

This works fine. But I want to display only functions with different Name attributes. It should only show me Function with Name A und the one with Name B, the last function with name A should not be included.

How can i do this? Any suggestions?
I'm using XQuery 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` to find functions with the same name:

```
for $func in /Content/Function
let $name := $func/@Name
group by $name
let $last-func := ($func/.)[last()]
return <Function Name="{$name}">{
  local:printAttributes($last-func)
}</Function>
```

Since the order inside groups is not standardized, you need to use a self step `/.` in `$last-func` to sort the elements in *document order*.

In XQuery 1.0 you can simulate `group by` by using `fn:distinct-values(...)`:

```
for $name in distinct-values(/Content/Function/@Name)
let $funcs := /Content/Function[@Name = $name]
let $last-func := $funcs[last()]
return <Function Name="{$name}">{
  local:printAttributes($last-func)
}</Function>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say I'm using XQuery 1.0
group doesnt seem to work there?

Comment: I have added a solution without `group by`.

Comment: Worked! Thank you a lot.